# What is the best way to test sendgrid parse API on a dev machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

I am developing a small web app that should receive emails from users, using sendgrid addon on Heroku. What is the best way to test this on a local dev machine? I was thinking about using [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) and set up a temporary url for that, but is there any other way I could do that? Also, how could it be tested with rspec or cucumber?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SendGrid Parse API needs to have a live URL, so using localtunnel should work, or other services like dyndns, since the Parse API just needs to contact your web app to do a POST operation. Check out the SendGrid docs for how to set it up and work with it.

Comment: i am marking your answer as accepted, because i ended up using localtunnel for that. Only thing is, i noticed that after a short period, the same localtunnel address gets assigned to somebody else and i start getting strange requests for my local testing app.